# What is the gene for height?

Tags: genetics

Height doesn't seem to be linked to sex, which is surprising. I have seen ways to predict children's height and it involves taking the average of both parents height. Upon my search, I did not find the actual gene for height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No single gene determines the height (a polygenic trait) of an individual. In fact, height is coded for by [over 700 genes](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature21039). Also, I'm caught quite off guard by your suggestion that height isn't linked to sex, which is obviously not true. [One gene that is associated with a shorter height (to put it simply), ITM2A, is expressed more strongly in women](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004127) and so helps explain a small (though not inconsequential) fraction of the height difference between men and women.